# Python - Fast Way to Remove Duplicates in This List?

Tags: python, list

You know, to turn list:

```
a = ["hello", "hello", "hi", "hi", "hey"]
```

into list:

```
b = ["hello", "hi", "hey"]
```

You simply do it like this:

```
b = list(set(a))
```

It's fast and pythonic.

But what if i need to turn this list:

```
a = [["hello", "hi"], ["hello", "hi"], ["how", "what"], ["hello", "hi"], 
     ["how", "what"]]
```

to:

```
b = [["hello", "hi"], ["how", "what"]]
```

What's the pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> a = [["hello", "hi"], ["hello", "hi"], ["how", "what"], ["hello", "hi"], ["how", "what"]]
>>> set(map(tuple, a))
set([('how', 'what'), ('hello', 'hi')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach which isn't as good (although it works for unhashable objects as long as they are orderable)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = [["hello", "hi"], ["hello", "hi"], ["how", "what"], ["hello", "hi"], ["how", "what"]]
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(sorted(a))]
[['hello', 'hi'], ['how', 'what']]
```

Comment: +1 for being the only one to not convert the lists to tuples.  His example has list of lists not list of tuples

Answer (score 0):

If the original order needs to be preserved and you have Python 2.7+

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = [["hello", "hi"], ["hello", "hi"], ["how", "what"], ["hello", "hi"], ["how", "what"]]
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(tuple, a)))
[('hello', 'hi'), ('how', 'what')]
```